# python minimalmodbus protocol implementation for SMC LEC 6: write to multiple coils

Tags: python, controller, modbus, modbus-tcp, minimalmodbus

`minimalmodbus` does not provide a way to set multiple coils at once. I cannot find a workaround.

### objective:

The modbus protocol description in the datasheet of the SMC LEC 6 controller, see [link](http://static1.1.sqspcdn.com/static/f/824646/25754058/1418151144707/SMC+LE+series+LEC+comm+info+-+Modbus+RTU.pdf?token=ueLGA1dG5mOOg0pHIeskyzRCiTs%3D).
I try to follow the directions from the example starting at page 7 by sending the listed modbus commands using the pyton library `minimalmodbus`.

I want to send the command `01 0F 00 10 00 08 01 02 BE 97` but do not find a way to do this with `minimalmodbus`. There is not implementation of *function code* 15 (`OF`).

### What I tried to do:

I reasoned as follows:

- I want to set multiple coils: `0F`
- Starting from position: `00 10`
- I want to set 8 coils: `00 08`, or one byte `01`
- What I want to do is set this byte to value 2 (`02`), or in binary `00000010`

I thought this could work by setting these positions all separately:

```py
logging.debug('write step')
step_address = int('0010', 16)

bin_2 = [0] * 8
bin_2[6] = 1

for pos, val in zip(list(range(8)), bin_2):
    contr.write_bit(step_address + pos, val)
time.sleep(WAIT_TIME)
contr.write_bit(flags['DRIVE'], 1); time.sleep(WAIT_TIME * 5)
```

The actuator does not move though...

Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to send the command in question by going a bit deeper in the minimal modbus class and sending the raw payload to the device:

`00 10 00 08 01 02`

```py
contr._performCommand(15, '\x00\x10\x00\x08\01\02')
contr.write_bit(flags['DRIVE'], 1)
time.sleep(WAIT_TIME * 3)
contr.write_bit(flags['DRIVE'], 0)
```